# I can't ask questions because my previous question was not asked properly as is implied. what should i do?

Tags: discussion

Please show what the problem is when my question is blocked?

Comment: You've asked [**five** questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/139788/k-k) over the past month. Which one in particular are you asking about here? Given those five questions have attracted only two upvotes between them (and one downvote), it might be you should consider asking future questions on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), where other users are more likely to be tolerant of poorly-phrased questions (on *that* site, the default assumption is that questioners aren't native speakers, and thus may not be able to express themseloves very well in English).

Comment: Thanks for recommending the right site.

Comment: I tend to think meta questions like yours are best answered by mods, but if that doesn't happen today perhaps I'll post my comment as an answer. I don't know why a couple of people downvoted your *Meta* question here (it seems to me it's an issue worth raising), but it may be because they don't think your questions on the *main* site are suitable for ELU. It's important to realise that ELL is not a "poor relation" to ELU, or a site for "dummies". But it *is* generally a better choice for non-native speakers, since they're the primary target audience there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ***It's important to realise that ELL is not a "poor relation" to ELU, or a site for "dummies"*** <-- Well put. Important point

Comment: @Araucaria: It's often been said of me that I do not suffer fools gladly, but I like to think that only normally applies in situations where someone disagrees with me on what I consider spurious grounds. Computers are getting smarter all the time, but they're still pretty dumb, and I've spent most of my working life trying to persuade them to do things I *know* they're capable of - they just need to be told *exactly* what to do, in terms they understand. Not that dissimilar to nns querants on ELL, really (who may be *much* smarter than me overall; they just don't know English so well).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, I don't know about that. We seem to get on ok now?

Comment: @Araucaria: Erm... are you claiming to be [the fule that proves the rule?](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+any+fule+kno%22) :) That's unlikely, since I'm sure you know far more than me about the formal grammatical rules and descriptions of English. I'm just more anarchistically-inclined than you, so I bet most of our "disagreements" net down to me either denying the existence of some rule you kno perfectly well, or claiming that it's okay to break it anyway.

Comment: Currently, you are not blocked from asking questions, so I'm not sure exactly what the problem is [there may have been an issue on October 24, though]. However, account blocking is [answered on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997).